# How to apply a probability to pulling values from a DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, probability, database

I am wondering what would be a good way to apply a probability to the selection of a value from a db (a NOSQL db).
For example, if the database only contained a load of destinations (i.e. Florida, Canada, Brazil etc).
I am looking to pull a random value (e.g. Florida) but then next time I want Florida to be much less likely to be retrieved. 
I hoping to do this on a user basis, so if one particular user pulled florida already it would have a lower probability, but for a different user it would still be the same.

I was thinking of having a probability field for each db entry, and when its pulled to lower the probability. So I could have a value that's between 0-100 and every time a value is pulled it goes down by say 20, but this doesn't really work as they would all end up at 0 and I couldn't really do this for multiple users.

Comment: Maybe store you cities with _id as numbers. For example {_id:2, city: "florida"}.. And then do some random/probability computation that will give you number that you desired. And then just find that city. Mongo doesn't allow to do some probability queries. So you have to adjust.

Comment: You can use fractional numbers to lower them down for example by 0.9, then you won't run out of numbers :)

Comment: Probability it's always a fraction, by definition, so as @vsevolod-goloviznin suggested, use fnumbers from 0 to 1. And instead of decreasing linearly, decrease it by a percentage, ie: 0.6 -10% = 0.54. This way you never arrive to 0